How to Check Firefox Bookmark Sync Status and Compare with Local Bookmarks?
How to see firefox bookmark sync status- how many bookmarks are in cloud, on machine?
In Google Chrome, you can use the URI chrome://sync-internals to view detailed sync information, including the number of bookmarks stored on your machine and in the cloud, as well as whether you have reached the bookmark limit.
Is there a similar feature or method in Firefox that allows me to:

Check the sync status of bookmarks.
See the number of bookmarks stored locally versus those synced with the cloud.
Determine if I have reached any bookmark limits?

Any guidance or steps to achieve this in Firefox would be greatly appreciated.

Firefox doesn't let you see the sync information.
However, you can check the sync status by going to Settings > Firefox Account to confirm that bookmarks are being synced.
AFAIK there isn't a known hard cap on the amount of bookmarks you're allowed to have.
